# how to use inner join queries for four tables

Tags: sql

I have four tables in my database(**notes**, **expense**, **category** and **items**).

**items** table will have so many items on the particular category id
items table have fields

`id(primary key), item name(text), unit(text), category id(foreign key)`

**category** table will have just two fields
category table have fields

`id(primary key), cat_id(integer), category name(text)`.

**notes** table is used to have a record for each shopping note.
notes table have fields

`note_id(primary key), date(DATE), total cost(integer)`.

**expense** table is used to store the items purchased and its corresponding quantity and price under the particular shopping note using note id as the foreign key
expense table has fields

`id(primary key), note_id(foreign key), quantity(integer), price(integer), item_name(text)`

When I input the from date,to date and a particular category i need the items under that category that was purchaed between the from and to date.
i need a query that will give output as:

```
ITEM NAME           TOTALQTY          TOTALPRICE
carrot                5kg                 500
```

can anyone help me with a solution??

Comment: select A.name,sum(C.unit),A.unit,sum(C.price) from items as A INNER JOIN categories as B ON (A.category=B._id) and items as A INNER JOIN expenses as C ON(A.name=C.item_name) and expenses as C INNER JOIN notes as D ON (C.Note_id=D._id)
where D.date1 between '2012-01-01' and '2012-03-31' and B.name='Vegetables'

Comment: @remss: When you use SUM(), you have to use GROUP BY in your query on the other columns. Add `GROUP BY A.name, A.unit` and see what happens

Comment: can any1 give me a solution please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select A.name, sum(C.unit), A.unit, sum(C.price) 
from items as A 
    INNER JOIN categories as B ON A.category=B._id
    INNER JOIN expenses as C ON A.name=C.item_name
    INNER JOIN notes as D ON C.Note_id=D._id
where 
    D.date1 between '2012-01-01' and '2012-03-31' and B.name='Vegetables'
group by
    A.name, A.unit
```

Comment: thanks alot for d help......instead of using C.unit,C.price i replaced it with A.name which was my requirement